# issue in adding two arraylist

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have two arrayList

```
ArrayList ar1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList ar2 = new ArrayList();
```

**ar1** is having values { A,B,C,D}
and **ar2** is having values {1,2,3,4}

I want to add these two array list such that
output should be

A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4

I have used
ar1.addrange(ar2);
and the output is like this
A
B
C
D
1
2
3
4

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like C# from the C-like syntax and the presence of the ArrayList.AddRange function. Probably using .NET 1.1, given the lack of generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
int max = Math.Max(ar1.Count, ar2.Count);
ArrayList ar3 = new ArrayList();

for (int i=0; i < max; i++)
{
    if (i < ar1.Count)
    {
       ar3.Add(ar1[i]);
    }
    if (i < ar2.Count)
    {
       ar3.Add(ar2[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for to describe that operation is 'zip'.

[MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) implements [zip](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Zip.cs) for Linq to Objects, so if you can use a newer version of .NET with Linq, you can just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new ArrayList to hold the solution...

```
ArrayList ar3 = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < ar1.Length; i++)
{
  ar3.Add(ar1[i]);
  ar3.Add(ar2[i]);
}
```

Comment: True. I was taking the question literally (exact array lengths).

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried this
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index 


and @John Buchanan and @chris I don't think so there is any property called ar1.Length? with ArrayList....

Answer (score 1):

Use a a List so that you avoid boxing! 
(Assuming the arrays are equal length)

```
List<Int32> fun = new List<Int32>();
for (Int32 i = 0; i < ar1.Length; ++i)
{
  fun.Add(ar1[i]);
  fun.Add(ar2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Parallelized solution that will produce better time performance (approximately double) with no extra space requirement, in case of larger number of elements:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

final ArrayList ar1 = new ArrayList();
ar1.add("A");
ar1.add("B");
ar1.add("C");
ar1.add("D");
final ArrayList ar2 = new ArrayList();
ar2.add("1");
ar2.add("2");
ar2.add("3");
ar2.add("4");

//Create a hashmap with size and loadfactor that prevent it
//from being expanded before filling it.
final HashMap ar3 = new HashMap(10, 0.9f);


//fill half the list by a thread
Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {

    int i = 0;
    for (Iterator it = ar1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        ar3.put(i, it.next()) ;
        i+=2;
    }
    }
};

//fill half the list by another thread
Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {

    int j = 1;
    for (Iterator it = ar2.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        ar3.put(j, it.next()) ;
        j+=2;
    }
    }
};

//start threads
thread1.start();
thread2.start();

//Let main waits for them
try {
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}

//print result
System.out.println(ar3.values());

}
```

}

Comment: That's wrong. The extra space requirement by the threads is in the order of hundrets of kilobytes just for the stack. Additionally, you are modifying a `HashMap`, which is explicitly documented as non-threadsafe, from multiple threads at the same time. Third, if an `InterruptedException` occurs, you still print a result, and this result is most likely not complete. Fourth, you depend on the `hashCode` of an Integer being exactly its value and `HashMap` using this hashCode unmodified. The latter assumption doesn't hold. Therefore, you output the values in a wrong order.

Comment: Fifth, creating a `Thread` took about one millisecond when I tested it, when the non-threaded code would only take some nanoseconds to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it should work fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    List<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr1.add("1");
    arr1.add("2");
    arr1.add("3");
    arr1.add("4");

    List<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr2.add("A");
    arr2.add("B");
    arr2.add("C");
    arr2.add("D");

    List<String> arr3 = mergeList(arr1, arr2);

    for (String string : arr3)
    {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}

public static List<String> mergeList(List<String> arr1, List<String> arr2)
{

    int i = 0;
    int size = arr2.size();

    for (String string : arr1)
    {
        if (size >= (i + 1))
        {
            arr2.add(i + 1, string);
            i = i + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            arr2.add(string);
        }
    }

    return arr2;

}
```